Emacs with terraform config files autocomplete
I'm trying to run autocomplete for terraform files in emacs like vscode does.
This is relevant part of the config:
(use-package company
  :ensure t
  :config
  (setq company-idle-delay 0.3
        company-minimum-prefix-length 1)
  :hook ((terraform-mode . company-mode)
         (lsp-mode . company-mode)))

(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :hook ((terraform-mode . lsp-deferred)))
(setq lsp-disabled-clients '(tfls))
(setq lsp-terraform-ls-prefill-required-fields t)

(company-quickhelp-mode)

;; Add Terraform support to lsp-mode
(add-hook 'terraform-mode-hook #'lsp)

(use-package terraform-mode
  :hook (terraform-mode . lsp-deferred))

With this settings emacs does not autocomplete any terraform related resources like aws_instance etc.
I'm more emacs user than admin and I'm not able to find where the problem can be.
Thank you for your help.

I think you need to run (company-terraform-init) in the buffer with your terraform code.  It would only complete the "resource", "data", etc. keywords without it.  After running that I get the completion you're looking for.
I couldn't get it to run automatically from a hook, such as terraform-mode-hook.  But if I run it manually it works.

Are you trying to answer this question, or get more feedback to help resolve a problem of your own? It isn't super clear which you're trying to do.

Answering.. Running (company-terraform-init) is required before company will autocomplete terraform resource types.

Adding a few more sentences and getting rid of the question at the start (don't ask, tell: "You need to run (company...) first and you do it this way..." will make this a better answer. Use the EDIT button to rephrase and improve your answer.
